# How can I create a new STATE in a button in Flash CS3?

Tags: flash, button, state

I'm trying to create a new state for a button, like when I take the mouse pointer out of the Hit Area and, doing this, it fires a small movieclip. How can I do it? I probably need some especific name for this state, like Hit or Over, right?

Answer (score 1):

you can't do that ... buttons are of type [`SimpleButton`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/SimpleButton.html), which only has 3 actual states and one hitarea ...

to do, what you want to do, you need to create a custom button component, subclassing `Sprite` or `MovieClip` ... don't forget to set `buttonMode` and `useHandCursor` to true ... if you want to be able, to edit it much like a button, the best will be creating a `MovieClip` subclass ... then you can create a `MovieClip`, which has a scene for each state, and you associate it with the class ... the class will have to stop the `MovieClip` to avoid strange behaviour ... and then you can listen to all type of mouse events, deciding, to which scene to jump ... well be a bit of work ... or you create a proper CS3/CS4 componenent ... or maybe you can find one ...

greetz

back2dos